# Unlock a thread from another thread in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, mutex

I'm not extensively knowledgeable in terms on the thread.h api of the C++11 (in fact I'm not familiar with thread progranmming either, but I read on it recently quite a lot and know about the concurrency and stuff like that) but I started using it and I'm facing a problem that I haven't really ever faced yet.

I have two thread functions, say these

```
std::thread(thread1, args); // Spawn thread 1
std::thread(thread2, args); // Spawn thread 2

[...]

int thread1(bunch of args)
{
     lock_thread_2();
     [do stuff]
     while (some condition) {
         [do stuff]
         unlock_thread_2();
     }
}

int thread2(bunch of args)
{
     while (some condition) {
         [do stuff]
         wait_for_thread1_to_unlock_me();
     }
}
```

I first thought about doing it with a std::mutex but I read it could be dangerous because the behavior is undefined if I unlock an already-unlocked mutex and on top of it it wouldn't work anyways as mutex.lock() doesn't necessarily pause the execution (it only does if the mutex is already locked) so it'd be quite horrendous to write, I'd have to couple unlock() and lock() calls together.

What's important to note here is that thread2's execution only is controlled by thread1, but thread2 will never lock thread1 in any fashion. Only thread2 gets locked by thread1, only thread1 controls the execution flow thread2, not otherwise.

How would you do that in a clean way, supported way? Would you be kind enough to give an example of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```
std::condition_variable cv;

int thread1(bunch of args)
{
     [do stuff]
     while (some condition) {
         [do stuff]
         cv.notify_one();
     }
}

int thread2(bunch of args)
{
     std::mutex mtx;
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);

     while (some condition) {
         [do stuff]
         cv.wait(lk);
     }
}
```

When [`wait()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) returns, either `cv` will have been `notify()`-ed... or there will have been a spurious wakeup. In an effort to handle the latter, it's often helpful to add a predicate.

Comment: `std::condition_variable::wait` actually expects a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> &` and a `Predicate` optionally, so your example won't work.

Comment: @dasdave Yes obviously. My example also has `[do stuff]` in it.

Comment: Is a spurious wakeup a particular situation in which the lock unlocks itself magically without any intervention? How can you use the "Predicate" do circumvent this? From what I just read the predicate member is a function that relies on a variable to insure the condition has effectively been signaled?

Comment: @Yannick [Spurious wakeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). In addition to `notify_one()`, you would set/increment some variable and then check in your predicate that that variable got set/incremented. Without knowing more about your code, I wouldn't know what solution to propose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::condition_variable`. It allows for you to notify a thread from another thread by using the `notify_one` or `notify_all` methods to resume one, or all threads waiting on the condition variable, repectively. In you code you can use it like this:

```
std::condition_variable my_var;

void thread1(args) {
    ...
    while(condition1) {
        ...
        my_var.notify_one();
    }
}

void thread2(args) {
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    ...
    while(condition2) {
        ...
        my_var.wait(lock);
    }
}
```

Be careful though, condition variables are subject to occasional spurious wake ups so you might want to loop the wait condition to check whether the wake up was valid or not, like this:

```
do {
    my_var.wait(lock);
} while(!valid_wakeup);
```

You can read more about `std::condition_variable` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: Thanks for the question. In your second block of code, the variable valid_wakeup I guess would have to be set by thread1 prior to calling notify_one(), and the put back to zero by thread2?

Comment: @Yannick Most likely yes, probably by using [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or something similar.